# Confirm enum with Decodable protocol

Tags: ios, swift, decodable

There is a struct with property of enum type:

```
struct TestStruct: Decodable {
    let id: Int
    let name: String
    let enumVar: SomeEnum
}

enum SomeEnum: String {
    case one = "1099"
    case two = "9090"
    case three = "878"
}
```

How to confirm the enum to Decodable protocol in order to parse the elements of TestStruct struct?

I tried the fallowing way, but it didn't work:

```
extension SomeEnum: Decodable {
    enum Key: String, CodingKey {
        case one = "1099"
        case two = "9090"
        case three = "878"
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: Key.self)

        if let one = try container.decodeIfPresent(Swifter.self, forKey: .one) {
            self = .one
        } else if let two = try container.decodeIfPresent(Swifter.self, forKey: .two) {
            self = .two
        } else if let twitter = try container.decodeIfPresent(Swifter.self, forKey: .three) {
            self = .three
        } else {
            self = .three
        }
    }
```

Comment: You don't need to write a custom decoder, Codable will handle RawRepresentable enums by itself.

Comment: Could you please show the JSON?

Comment: @Sulthan

What I'm trying to parse in playground:

let json = """
[{
    "name": "Federico Zanetello",
    "id": 123456,
    "enumVar": "878"
},
  {
    "name": "John Firr",
    "id": 9898989,
    "enumVar": "9090"
  },
  {
    "name": "Bill Dough",
    "id": 7657,
    "enumVar": "1099"
  }]
""".data(using: .utf8)!